# How to handle unbalanced brackets with string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

I have the following code that interpolates values in strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict
"This is {foo} {bar}".format_map(defaultdict(str, **{"foo": "a test"}))

>>> 'This is a test '
```

This interpolates known values and replaces unknown values with an empty string.

But if I write an unbalanced bracket in the string:

```
"This is {foo} {bar]".format_map(defaultdict(str, **{"foo": "a test"}))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: expected '}' before end of string
```

Is there a way I can avoid this error and get the following output?

```
"This is {foo} {bar]".format_map(defaultdict(str, **{"foo": "a test"}))

>>> 'This is a test {bar]'
```

Comment: Catch the error ?

Comment: @PDHide Sure, I can catch the error, but then what? I still want to get a partially interpolated string instead of no string at all.

Comment: Have a look at the Template class in the `string` library. It’s all builtin.  Will work on an answer ...

Comment: @alexandernst can't you use regular expression to find valid format and replace it with value in dictionary instead of using format?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

You can escape curly bracket using double curly

Comment: @PDHide It may be theoretically possible, but in practice I don't I'd be comfortable with such a solution. But then again, I haven't actually seen any code implementing this, so maybe I could change my mind once I see / test such an implementation.

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirements? Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021017/how-to-handle-unbalanced-brackets-with-string-formatting/65021639?noredirect=1#comment114958469_65021639) implies manually rewriting the input is not possible. What input do you consider valid? What is the use-case such malformed strings in the first place? When concatenating your own format strings with user-provided strings, doing the formatting before the concatenation avoids the problem. If users provide the format string, which behaviour of format strings do they expect to be honoured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `Template` class of the built-in `string` library.

[Official Python docs on the class](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#template-strings).

Essentially, use a dollar sign before the variable which is to be replaced, as shown here. Then, call the `substitute()` function and pass in a `dict` with the replacement values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import Template

s = Template("This is $foo {bar]")

s.substitute({'foo': 'a test'})
>>> 'This is a test {bar]'
```

Or, in your specific case using `defaultdict`:

```
s.substitute(defaultdict(str, **{'foo': 'a test'}))
>>> 'This is a test {bar]'

s.substitute(defaultdict(str, **{'BOB': 'a test'}))
>>> 'This is  {bar]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Format strings, both for [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), begin a format field by `{`. This is not dependent on whether the field is ever closed.

Escape the brace as `{{` to show that it is a literal brace, not the beginning of a format field.

```py
>>> "This is {foo} {{bar]".format_map(defaultdict(str, **{"foo": "a test"}))
'This is a test {bar]'
```

Comment: The question arrises because of a mistyped string (coming from an end user, perhaps). Escaping the bracket is something not feasible in this situation.

Comment: @alexandernst Then none of the other answers will work, either. The accepted answer also requires rewriting the string, for example. Just to be clear, you are looking for a way to safely format *arbitrary* input strings? Are users aware of string formatting taking place, i.e. will they expect format fields and escaped braces to be honored?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get interpolated the most (if not all) of arbitrary user input. In case something is missing / wrong, I'd like to just skip that bit and move on to the next part of the string. The accepted solution will do exactly that, while your requires the users to be aware of "escaping".

Comment: @alexandernst The accepted answer also requires users to be aware of escaping. For example, ``${foo]`` is an invalid template field and would need escaping as ``$${foo]``; likewise, ``$$foo`` would be accidental escaping when not aware of it. Any embedded format syntax has escaping, on account of replacing otherwise valid character meaning. Thus, my question what you actually consider to be viable input.